# Prove the limit: $\lim [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n] = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Prove the limit: $\lim [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n] = \frac{1}{4}$

**Discussion:** Assume that we can make $\big| [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n]- \frac{1}{4}\big|$to fall down any given number. Given an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon \gt 0$, we assume
$$
\big| [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n] -  \frac{1}{4}\big| \lt \varepsilon $$
$$
\big| [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n]\big| \lt \varepsilon + 1/4$$
Now, we have two problems here, first that we cannot fully isolate $n$ and second $n$ doesn't occur in denominator as in fractional sequences. Without hurting anyone's feelings we would try to solve the second issue first:
$\text{Let's irrationalise the denominator of the expression of the given sequence}$
$\frac{ \left(\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n\right) ~\left( \sqrt{4n^2 +n} + 2n\right)}{ \sqrt{4n^2 +n} +2n}$
$\frac{n }{  \sqrt{4n^2 +n} + 2n} = \frac{1}{  \sqrt{4 +1/n} + 2}$

Let's simply our expression $ \big| [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n] -  \frac{1}{4}\big| = \big| \frac{1}{  \sqrt{4 +1/n} - 2} - 1/4\big| = 1/4 - \frac{1}{  \sqrt{4 +1/n} - 2}~~~\text{ for all} n \in \mathbf{N}$

Now, it's time for solving the first issue, that is to make ##n## floatable, for that we will estimate our original expression by something bigger than that (this is my official argument, that I claim the following expression to be less that epsilon)
$$
1/4 - \frac{1}{  \sqrt{4 +1/n} - 2} \lt 1/4 - \frac{1}{4 +1/n +2} = 1/4 - \frac{1}{6+ 1/n} \lt \varepsilon
$$
$$1/4 - \frac{1}{6+ 1/n} \lt \varepsilon\\
1/4 - \varepsilon \lt \frac{1}{6+1/n} \\
6/4 - 6 \varepsilon + 1/n ( 1/4 - \varepsilon) \lt 1\\
1/n ( 1/4 - \varepsilon) \lt 6 \varepsilon - 1/2 \\
n \gt \frac{2 (1/4 - \varepsilon) }{12 \varepsilon -1}$$

**Formal Proof:**

For any given arbitrarily small $\varepsilon \gt 0$ take $ N = \frac{2 (1/4 - \varepsilon) }{12 \varepsilon -1}$
$$n \gt N \implies n \gt \frac{2 (1/4 - \varepsilon) }{12 \varepsilon -1}\\
1/n \lt \frac{12 \varepsilon -1}{2 (1/4 - \varepsilon)}\\
 1/n ( 1/4 - \varepsilon) \lt 6\varepsilon -1/2\\
6/4 - 6\varepsilon + 1/n(1/4 - \varepsilon) \lt 1 \\
1/4 - \varepsilon \lt \frac{1}{6 + 1/n}\\
1/4 - \frac{1}{4 + 1/n +2} \lt \varepsilon\\
1/4 - \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{ 4 +1/n} +2 } \lt 1/4 - \frac{1}{4 + 1/n +2} \lt \varepsilon\\
1/4 - \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{ 4 +1/n} +2 } \lt \varepsilon \\
\big| \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{ 4 +1/n} +2 } - 1/4 \big| \lt \varepsilon\\
\big| [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n] - 1/4 \big| \lt \varepsilon$$

Thus, we can the expression $ \big| [\sqrt{4n^2 +n} - 2n] - 1/4 \big|$ to fall below any given number.

So, basically there were three important steps:

1. First get $n$ in denominator.
2. Estimate the original expression by something else, so as to make $n$ to move freely.
3. Judiciously removing the bars of absolute values.

EDIT:
Theo Bandit found the mistake and here is the amend:

2nd expression of 5th para of Discussion section:

$$
\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4 +1/n -2} \lt \varepsilon \\
1/4 - \frac{1}{2+1/n} \lt \varepsilon \\
n \gt \frac{1/4 - \varepsilon}{1/2+ \varepsilon}$$

So, the correct $N$ is $N = \frac{1/4 - \varepsilon}{1/2+ \varepsilon}$. As all our steps were reversible, we can easily establish the formal proof by this new $N$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want us to verify your proof, please say clearly, and please say clearly what you were unsure of in your reasoning

Comment: Alarm bells are ringing about that $N$ expression. What if $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{12}$? If $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{12}$, then $N$ is negative, suggesting that any $n > 0$ should put $\sqrt{4n^2 + n} - 2n$ within $\varepsilon$ of $\frac{1}{4}$, which could only be true if the sequence were constant!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I need a verification of my proof from someone who had passed the stage in which I’m now. And for that purpose, I would take your response as valuable.

Comment: @FShrike Initially, I put at last “Please comment your views on my proof”, but then I removed it thinking that a site which doesn’t allow “thank you” and “Good Afternoon” would surely get satiated by “solution-verification” tag.

Comment: For what value of $x$ are you trying to find the limit?

Comment: @TheoBendit Got the mistake: 2nd expression of 5th para of Discussion section. It should $$\frac{1}{4+ 1/n -2}$$ I, by mistake, got +2 there.

Comment: @ShimuraVariety The exercise is from Ross’ Analysis, and he, when works for limits of sequences, doesn’t not write “as n goes to infinity”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating... You can just consider an upper bound that is easier to handle. For instance,
$$
|\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n -\frac 14|=\left|\dfrac{4n^2+n-(2n+\frac 14)^2}{\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n+\frac 14}\right|=\dfrac{1/16}{(\cdots)}< \frac{1}{32n}
$$

This way, given $\varepsilon >0$, you can choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{32N} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: more strong < 1/16/(4n) < 1/64n

Comment: @AlexGlebe Yes, but just kept the $2n$ term in the denominator but you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much faster if you use the Taylor expansion:
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x)\;
, \qquad x\to 0.$$
In fact:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n &= 2n\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n}}-1\bigg)
=2n\Bigg(\bigg(1+\frac{1}{8n}+o\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\bigg)-1\Bigg)
\\
&= \frac{1}{4}+o(1)\;, \qquad n\to\infty\;.
\end{align*}

Or, if you don't know Taylor expansions, rely on $(a+b)\cdot(a-b) = a^2 -b^2$ to obtain:
\begin{align*}
   \sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n
&=
   \frac{\big(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n) \cdot \big(\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n)}{\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n}
\\
&=
   \frac{4n^2+n-4n^2}{\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n}
=
   \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n}}+1} \to \frac{1}{4}\;, \qquad n \to \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: I think the point is not to compute the limit, but rather to prove that it is $\frac 14$ using the definition of limit.

Comment: It does not change the conclusion, but sorry to write that the last denominator involving the root is wrong.

Comment: Thx, typo corrected

Answer (score 1):

Given the particular closed form of the sequence elements
$$\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n\;=\; \sqrt{2n\left(2n+\frac12\right)}-2n$$
the Harmonic-Geometric-Arithmetic mean inequalities are apt to obtain a fairly quantitative assertion of the convergence
$$\frac1{4+\frac1{2n}} \:=\:\frac2{\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n+\frac12}}-2n \:<\: \sqrt{2n\left(2n+\frac12\right)}-2n \:<\: \frac{2n\;+\;2n+\frac12}2-2n \:=\: \frac14\,,$$
that is we obtain a lower and an upper limit squeezing the sequence terms.
As $\,2n\,$ and $\,2n+\frac12\,$ are never equal, the stronger "$<$" holds instead of "$\leqslant$" .

The above inequality chain may be transformed into the equivalent
$$0\:<\: \frac14-\big(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n\big)\:<\: \frac1{32n+4}\,,$$
from which given some $\,\varepsilon > 0\,$ a corresponding $N(\varepsilon)$
can be readily read off.